# Film about ancient hypnotist magician who uses hypnosis to control people around him

Tags: story-identification, movie, mind-control

I remember that the protagonist (average looking white guy) was fighting an ancient sorcerer/magician who looked like a Mongol/Chinese guy and was using hypnosis to control people around him.

The magician had a sentient knife which he called "Chimera" and there was a scene where the protagonist tried to mind-control the knife.

I watched this film somewhere back in early 2000's, and I guess the film was recent at this point, because the graphics were quite good.

I don't remember the plot details, only several scenes:

- the magician is throwing a guy in a uniform over the edge of high building.
- the protagonist is naked and chained to a statue of living metal with many arms (or something looking like this).

Comment: You have a decent start here but can you read [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) and [edit] in some more details? For example, when did you see this? Was it new then? Do you know what the plot/story was or just these points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [*The Shadow*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111143/) (1994)

Our hero fights a Mongol descendant of Genghis Khan with a fancy flying psychic knife called the "Phurba".

Comment: I was going to suggest that.

Comment: The knife had a head/face if I recall.

Comment: @Verdan - It did indeed. You can see it at 3:04 in the clip above